# How far (and why!) do Android alarms execute in the past?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have had several frustrations with setting alarms in Android. I have tried setting repeating/non-repeating alarms and exact/inexact alarms but it does not matter, if the alarm is ever set for a time in the past, it executes as soon as it is set. I have tested this as far back as setting an alarm for 5 hours in the past and is still executes immediately.

For example:

The time is 7 AM and I set an alarm to execute at 2 AM. This is obviously meant for the next time the clock reads 2:00 AM but it does not matter, the alarm goes off at 7 AM, right after it is set.

The code below should select a random time between 1:00 AM and 3:59 AM to set/execute the alarm for the next calendar day and then the logic circles back around to set itself again after execution. The alarm will execute repeatedly, forever.

```
    int randomHour = new Random().nextInt((3 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    int randomMinute = new Random().nextInt((59 - 1) + 1) + 1;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, randomHour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, randomMinute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Questions:

1. At what point does Android stop executing alarms in the past?
2. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*This is obviously meant for the next time"* Does not work for computers, they will do exactly what you tell them to do.

`calendar.getTimeInMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT. You need to specify not just the time but also the date that you want the alarm to go off. Instead you are always calling `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` (the first day of the current month)